# Angular2 creating models

Tags: angular, typescript

I get a response from my server as following:

```
{
  "coreGoalId": 0,
  "title": "string",
  "effect": "string",
  "target_Audience": "string",
  "infrastructure": "string",
  "benefits": [
    {
      "benefitId": 0,
      "what": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0
    }
  ],
  "steps": [
    {
      "stepId": 0,
      "what": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "imagelId": 0,
      "base64": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0
    }
  ],
  "subGoals": [
    {
      "subGoalId": 0,
      "title": "string",
      "priority": "string",
      "audience": "string",
      "social_aspects": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0,
      "issues": [
        {
          "issueId": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "subGoalID": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In short, a CoreGoal has some attributes along with a list of benefits, steps etc. It has SubGoals which in turn has many Issues.

What could be the best way to create Angular2 models for such a schema? I will have a single HTTP GET request which will fetch all the coreGoals, and have a single HTTP PUT request which will update individual CoreGoal. So basically I will be manually building such a JSON object before making a PUT request.

Am I supposed to make separate classes for Benefits, Steps etc?

Comment: We have no idea whether you use Dart, javascript, or typescript?

Comment: I'd say you should create a `class` for each attribute that can be used as a collection

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I am using Typescript.

Comment: @FabioG I was reading a few blogposts which suggested using Interfaces, so I was not sure

Comment: @Nitish use interfaces ;-). I personnally use this tool : http://json2ts.com/

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Thanks for the suggestion and this tool! Is there any good tutorial which shows how Interfaces can be used in Angular2 apps?